# google maps marker cursor

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need some advise to change a marker cursor. I have this code:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker( {map: g_map_obj,
                                  clickable: true,
                                  draggable: true,
                                  position: e.latLng,
                                  visible: true,
                                  title: "hola",
                                  cursor: g_static_files +"eraser.cur",
                                  icon: g_static_files + 'castle.png'} );
```

... but this doesn't work.

Comment: You should post a bit of context: specifically the creation of the `g_map_obj` and the `e.latLng` variables are of interest.

Comment: g_map_obje : map variable and e.latLng: position from gmap event function. The marker is drawed but it doesn't show muy cursor

Comment: I meant the actual code you use to construct these objects: they might contain some weird value, or are of the wrong type and such. It helps to see the code that creates these object.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a problem with the .cur file type.  Try using a .png instead.